# What are all of the operation types supported in Tezos?

Tags: rpc, operation

Is there a way to query for a complete list of operation types that are supported in Tezos?

Answer (score 7):

```
$ ./tezos-client rpc schema post /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/forge/operations | jq '.input.definitions."operation.alpha.contents".oneOf | .[] | .properties.kind.enum | .[0]'
"endorsement"
"seed_nonce_revelation"
"double_endorsement_evidence"
"double_baking_evidence"
"activate_account"
"proposals"
"ballot"
"reveal"
"transaction"
"origination"
"delegation"
```